# group by using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

```
china_map2<-china_map  %>% group_by(Country) %>% mutate(sum=sum(ODA))
```

I am trying to add the value by country, but I keep getting the overall sum of all countries.
I would like to get the sum value for each country, but I get one result adding all values.
Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data (some or all of `china_map`) in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(china_map)`, or `dput(head(china_map, 20))`. I have to point out that the name of the variable suggests it may contain only one country :)

Comment: Try using `china_map2<-china_map  %>% group_by(Country) %>% dplyr::mutate(sum=sum(ODA)) `